# Como colocar este menu no meu aplicativo?

Tags: android

Ele tem um botão que ao clicar ou deslizar para o lado ele abrirá o menu e aparecerá as opções

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: este menu é um componente chamado navigation drawer
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html?hl=pt-br

a propria pagina do desenvolvedor oferece treinamento com exemplo de navigation drawer

Comment: caso queira uma explicação eu gosto de usar o thiengo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xpA1bY_TX4&list=PLBA57K2L2RIKq7_IpaZRTL96CyLNDzF2F&index=5

 ele explica muito bem muitas funcionalidades do Material Design que usamos, menus, recycler view, este drawer...

Comment: Show de bola , obrigado @DanielGentil